# Can the woman from The Ring appear in multiple places at once?

Tags: the-ring

Apologies for the speculative question,  but I was inspired by the reddit thread:

[[The Ring] What would happen if during a live broadcast of the Super Bowl the Ring movie interrupted the broadcast?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/41ueyn/the_ring_what_would_happen_if_during_a_live/)

Having not watched any of the movies, I was stumped.  Such a limitation seems like it would ruin the horror of the spirit in question. As one user puts it:

> She would be so inundated (Assuming she isnt able to be in multiple places at once) that even if she killed a person every 15 minutes she is only killing 35,000 people a year.
>   Assuming 115 million people watched the superbowl it will take her 3286 years to kill all of them if she never had to stop or take a break and could travel quickly.

Is there anything in any ring story that would refute that?

Comment: Just the conversion from urban legend to common knowledge that this wraith was out there remorsely killing avid and casual football fans alike, day after day, year after year, would profoundly change civilization.

Comment: also on this topic, what would happen if someone catches and restrains her?

Answer (score 6):

Not in the 2002 English-language movie, but that movie is based on a 1998 Japanese film which is in turn based on a 1991 Japanese novel, both of which are called *Ring* or *Ringu*.

In both of these source documents, the story has a different structure from the English movie: a reporter with an interest in supernaturalism starts investigating an incident of a recently-deceased teenager, only to find that they were only one of several who were in *different places* but all died *simultaneously*, as in at-the-same-time-on-the-same-day eerie-coincidence simultaneous. The outward manifestation of this dying is something akin to a seizure, with the cause of death noted by coroners as some sort of heart attack.

However this canon is not internally consistent; the film varies considerably from the book as well on the crucial question of "does this girl who was traumatized murder those who watch the tape?" In the novel, the agent of death is actually a psychically-activated ghost of a smallpox virus. The internal psychology of the smallpox virus -- to cause a "host" to duplicate itself -- is why the tape demands to be copied and recopied. With this background, it's not actually clear that the images have power outside of the physical tape which they live in, it's more that you are "infected by a ghost" which will only be satisfied if you make two more of them.